# Scroll to a Textview in nestedscrollview by clicking a button

Tags: android, button, scroll, textview

I am using a scrolling activity.I have few TextViews and buttons in my content_scrolling.xml and i want to programmically scroll/jump to a particular textview when a particular button is clicked.

Also, i dont want to use the functions involving x-y coordinates.

Basically, I dont know what to do in OnClick(View v) function of the button.

My content_scrolling.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.admin.test2.ScrollingActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling"
android:id="@+id/nsv">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text1"
            android:id="@+id/b1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text2"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text3"
            android:id="@+id/b3" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1"
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/l1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2"
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/t1"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_height"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text3"
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/t2"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/app_bar_height"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: "Also, i dont want to use the functions involving x-y coordinates."   Why?!!

Comment: well..i am looking for a universal method which can be called in almost all my activities.....x-y coordinates will restrict it to a specific activity

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the scrollTo(x,y) method of ScrollView.

```
your_scrollview.scrollTo(0, your_TextView.getBottom());
```

your_TextView is textview you want to scroll to it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been looking for the answer a good time.